# WordPress Pages are not showing in the pages section and it is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have created an wordpress site. Then I created a custom page as a home page. I have also some pages. After some days, I have not found pages in the dashbord and as home page shows index.php page

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code at top of your template-page

```
<?php
```

/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
?>

OR

go->setting->reading->set front page->home page
    and blog page-->blog and save